# Angular loader and RxJS combineLatest

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

Hi I am working on the Angular application. I want to add a global loader which is shown whenever I am fetching some data from my api. I've got the ngrx `fetchDataAction`, this action sets the loading property to true in the store and two additional actions `fetchDataActionSuccess` and `fetchDataActionFailure`, those two actions sets the data if everything goes properly or shows the error when something goes wrong, they also set the loading property in the store to false. I've got a lot of different loader states and corresponding actions as described above, for example for fetching users, books and orders:

- usersLoading
- booksLoading
- ordersLoading

Now I want to show and hide the loader based upon those states, so I've got the following logic in my global loader component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.loadingSubscription = combineLatest([
        this.usersFacade.usersLoading$,
        this.booksFacade.booksLoading$,
        this.ordersFacade.ordersLoading$
    ])
    .pipe(isAnyTrue())
    .subscribe(isLoading => this.loaderService.toggleLoader(isLoading))
}
```

The userLoading$ is a selector for the userLoading state. Is it okay to use the combineLates operator in this particular situation?

Comment: When you say global loader why don't you do things in from the HTTP interceptor? Turn on the loader when the request leaves and disable the loader when you get anything if it is successful load the data else show the error code. You can create error interceptor too.

Comment: Sometimes I do multiple request on the single page, so for example if the first request takes 1s and the second one takes 2s, I will show the loader and hide it after 1s, but the second request will be still in progress, so I have to take all the loaders into consideration.

Comment: Considering all those observables emit at least one value, yes `combineLatest()` is appropriate for this situation.

Comment: As @JoshuaMcCarthy `combineLatest` needs all it's items to emit at least one value to emit. However this aproach won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `combineLatest` also solves the problem and is not a particularly bad approach, there is a better way of doing this, which is using `createSelector` to combine several existing selectors (like the ones that your facade classes provide) into one big selector, which sends values whenever one of them changes. You can see an example on how this is done [here](https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/avoid-combining-selectors.md). So you can create a selector, say `globalLoading`, combine all loading selectors, and return if any one of them is true.